# VBA ADODB recordset is closed

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ado

I am trying to query a database using Excel VBA and write to a sheet. The VBA code I have works fine for one server/database, but when I try to pull from a different database it messes up.

When I run this on this database, I get an error stating "Operation is not allowed when object is closed." on `With mrs` line. I don't understand why the object is closed when I opened it two lines before.

SQL query has `nocount on` and `ansi_warnings off`.

Here is the associated VBA Code:

```vb
Dim strFileContent As String
Dim massiveString As String

Sub runSelectedQueries()
    Call runQuery(Sheet3, "dbp07", "OLBRET", "C:\Queries\query.sql")
End Sub

Private Sub runQuery(outputSheet As Worksheet, serverVar As String, databaseVar As String, queryLoc As String)
    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;driver={SQL Server}; server=" & serverVar & "; Integrated Security=SSPI; database=" & databaseVar & ";"
     MsgBox (sconnect)

    'run readFile sub
    readAnyFile (queryLoc)

    'parse SQL file into string    
    sSQLString = massiveString

    Conn.Open sconnect
    mrs.Open sSQLString, Conn

    'write in the master record set (mrs) into a sheet
    With mrs
       For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
           outputSheet.Cells(1, i) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
       Next i
    End With
    outputSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

    'Close Recordset
    mrs.Close

    'Close Connection
    Conn.Close

End Sub

'reads any file as input (text) not binary using EOF, stripping the metadata at begining of a file    
Sub readAnyFile(queryLoc As String)

    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String
    massiveString = ""

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open queryLoc For Input As #FileNum

    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
        massiveString = massiveString + DataLine
    Wend

    massiveString = Right(massiveString, Len(massiveString) - 2)

    MsgBox ("Read Successfully")
    MsgBox (massiveString)

End Sub
```

When I debug and push out the SQL code that is read from a file, I get exactly what is in SQL Server Management Studio. The SQL statement runs fine in MS Query, Python and SQL Server Management Studio as parsed by VBA so I don't think that's the issue but I could post it.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line? That line does not do anything and cannot raise errors.

Comment: `sSQLString` is never declared.  Did you mean `sSQLQry`?  Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module and fix your declarations\assignments.

Comment: Would `massiveString` be instantiated for that sub as its declared as a `Dim` in that module? Also I don't see where you are reading your SQL code to your variable. Should it have been `massiveString = readAnyFile (queryLoc)`?